# Modifying the wordpress login page and then referencing it with a shortcode problem

Tags: shortcode, hooks, login, forms

Both parts are working great separately. I have made the shortcode for the login form with:

```
//register new shortcode
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_shortcodes' );

function my_add_shortcodes() {

    add_shortcode( 'my-login-form', 'my_login_form_shortcode' );
}



// login shortform code
function my_login_form_shortcode() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
        return '';
    return $form_html . wp_login_form( array( 
        'echo' => false,
        'form_id' => 'loginform',
        ) 
    ); 
}
```

And modifying the login form to have an extra note on it:

```
add_action( 'login_form', 'login_extra_note', 1 );

function login_extra_note() {

    //Adding the text

?>
<p>You can type a little note to those logging in here.</p>

<?php
}
```

The /wp-login.php page shows the extra note. The shortcode shows a login form.

**But** the shortcode [my-login-form] shows the default login form, not the updated one with a note.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My fix was to change 'login_form' to 'login_form_middle' and to change the straight text dumping of "You can add a ..." into a string that I return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_login_form`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/) is completely separate from `wp-login.php` - the `login_form` hook only applies to the latter.

For the former, you've got three filters at your disposal:

1. `login_form_top` - return HTML to be injected right after the opening `<form />` tag
2. `login_form_middle` - return HTML to be injected between the password field and the remember me/submit field
3. `login_form_bottom` - return HTML to be injected right before the closing `</form>`

Comment: You are too fast in typing :D Just a note the best replacement of `login_form` here is `login_form_middle`!